# Trigger ng-change on load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have multiple checkbox being rendered on page, i would like to trigger `ng-change()` if my checkbox has been checked on load.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-true-value="true" 
      ng-false-value="false"
        ng-change="CustomCheckSelect(someValue)" ng-model="model.defaultCheckBox"/>
```

Using `ng-init` is causing me problems and throwing errors in console as some of them are not checked.

Comment: How are you setting value `checked` on load? Also instead of having function on change, you can have a $watch on it.

Comment: share all the files and code u have tried. If possible add ur code in plunker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs about [ngChange](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange):

> The ngChange expression is **only** evaluated when a **change** in the **input**
>   value causes a **new value** to be committed to the model.

Even if you would trigger the `ng-change`, let's say with `ng-model-options`:
 `ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'onload default'}"`
it wouldn't get evaluated because you are not changing any value.

If you don't like the `ngInit` solution you can try manually invoking the function in the controller.

So you have one `$scope.model` and some of the properties are handled by `checkboxes` let's say `defaultCheckbox` and `secondaryCheckbox`.

To avoid repetition I would store these values in an array and then iterate and call the function `CustomCheckSelect` by condition:

```
var checkboxes = ['defaultCheckbox', 'secondaryCheckbox'];

angular.forEach(checkboxes, function(val){
    if ($scope.model[val]) {
        $scope.CustomCheckSelect(val);
    }
})
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HBjXWUMvamZJXAOh2A4D?p=preview)

Answer (score 6):

Try this. Write a `<div></div>` with ng-if and check whether "**model.defaultCheckBox**" is true or false. Call a method in ng-init from that div. Like-

```
<div  
    ng-if="model.defaultCheckBox"  ng-init="CustomCheckSelect(somevalue)">
</div>
```